# C# Listbox set selected item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem, selected

i have a C# listbox with the values

```
Profile 1
Profile 2
Profile 3
```

I want to have **Profile 2** selected when the form loads. How do I do this?

Comment: You mean a Winforms listbox? C# itself can be used with many different UI frameworks...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the [`ListBox.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx) property in the [`Form.Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event.
For example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Adding the event handler in the constructor
    this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
}    

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myListBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put following code in `Form.Loaded` event:

```
listBox1.SelectedItem = "Profile 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Profile 1");

listBox1.Items.Add("Profile 2");

listBox1.Items.Add("Profile 3");

listBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```