# Listbox does not contain definition for SetSelected

Tags: c#, listbox

So I'm making a program on c# that would look written textbox text from the listbox items when you click a button. And if it finds items that have a same name as in the textbox it would higlight them. The problem is that I get an error saying that: Listbox does not contain definition for SetSelected.[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h5Uk.jpg)

Comment: Dont post your code in a screenshot. Also `listBox.SelectedIndex = 5`

Comment: If you want something like `SetSelected` write an extension method. Or you could use `.SelectedIndex` like EpicKip said or `.SelectedItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
listBox1.SelectedItem = "Something";
```

---

- [C# Listbox set selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453439/c-sharp-listbox-set-selected-item)

**EDIT:**
In your case it will be:

```
lstPelit.SelectedIndex = i;
```